# Structure of operand bytes in .NET call and data access IL instructions?

Tags: ida, windows, malware, .net

I tried googling but couldn't find any good source that explains the structure of memory access instructions like ldstr and call instructions

for example based on experience, the last byte of API/library call instructions is always 0x0A (let me know if I'm wrong), but why? what are the structure of the 4 bytes of call operands? what about operands of ldstr instructions?

because they are different from native apps, they are not raw offsets, they seem to be offsets into a table but i cannot find any post that explains this in detail?

the best thing i found is this :

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-clr-metadata-1/

but it still doesn't explain many things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the last byte of API/library call instructions is always `0x0A`

It's because calls needs to have method (ref) as a parameter and methods are defined in the table that has an id of `0x0A`.

Having bytes of the call like this `280600000A` let's go one by one.

- `0x28` - is the value for opcode 'call' and it takes one operand.
- the rest of the opcode is the metadata token so basically the information which method should be called

But why `0x0A` is at the end? It should be read as a little-endian so the value should be `0x0A000006`. But what are the bytes?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata_(CLI)):

> When CIL code uses metadata it does so through a metadata token. This is a 32-bit value where the top 8 bits identify the appropriate metadata table, and the remaining 24 bits give the index of the metadata in the table.

So the first value is the table id - and as I've mentioned the id of member's ref table is value `0x0A`. And the rest is an index in the table (in our case `0x6`).

More about the tables? Those are basically part of .NET metadata information, that can be seen when you open one in i.e. dnSpy

[image]

As one can see `0x0A` is assigned to the `MemberRef` (containing both methods and fields references)

> what about operands of ldstr instructions?

In this instance, the instruction has the following structure `72XXXX0070` and `0x70` indicates different stream - namely User defined strings or `#US`. The rest (again interpreted as a little-ending 32-bit val) is the offset (in bytes) in `#US` table.

Generally dnSpy is a great tool to verifying those values as one can metadata tables.

The linked article (and the whole series is a great resource)  it does explain (I think) the structure but maybe indirectly - just find the information about metadata token.

We can induce from it the whole structure of a metadata token.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, do you happen to know any other good reference or even a book that explains everything about structure of .NET files/IL instructions in a very detailed manner?  what is the most detailed reference?

Comment: Not sure if I can provide one reference. It is something I acquired by reading & exploring multiple sources.

Comment: Multiple sources are fine too, would appreciate if you can share them.